# Apache POI getBodyHtml is returning null

Tags: java, apache, outlook, apache-poi, msg

I need to parse some data inside a table from a .msg file(Outlook) and I'm using apache poi to extract the data. The problem I have is that getHtmlBody() returns null but the getTextBody() and getRtfBody() works. I even sent myself a mail with HTML wich should be standard in the mail. But it's still null.

Is there anyone else who's been having this issue? I'm using this example:
[Apache POI Example](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hsmf/examples/Msg2txt.java?view=markup) even if I change the msg.getTextBody() to msg.getHtmlBody() on row 100 I get null.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just fetch the rich text RTF part, and process that? (Outlook often stores "rich" emails as RTF not html)

Comment: I did that, but I do not get the <table> <td> and <tr> tags. I only get <span> tags. When I sent myself a test mail the format was html as standard and the body was still null.

Comment: Apache POI is just giving you what Outlook decided to store in the file. POI can't help if Outlook did something stupid :(

Comment: Ah! Thanks alot for your input.